# How to replace matched values based on ther index .replace() javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an object

```
{
  key: "#% chance to gain Unholy Might for # seconds on Kill", 
  value: [
    [10, 15],
    [3, 3]
  ]
}
```

I need to replace key "#" in order:

- first "#" = value[0]
- second "#" = value[1]

end key must look `(10-15)% chance to gain Unholy Might for 3 seconds on Kill`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate over the values using [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). Then for every value update the text using [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```js
const data = {
  key: "#% chance to gain Unholy Might for # seconds on Kill", 
  value: [
    [10, 15],
    [3, 3]
  ]
};

const replateBy = (text, token, values) => {
  return values.reduce((text, [a,b])=>  text.replace(token, `${a===b ? a: `(${a}-${b})`}`), text);
}
console.log(replateBy(data.key, "#", data.value));
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is with a [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). Since the first `#` is followed by a percentage sign we can just replace `#%` to start off with, which then leaves us with just the last `#` to replace.

```js
const data = {
  key: "#% chance to gain Unholy Might for # seconds on Kill", 
  value: [
    [10, 15],
    [3, 3]
  ]
}

// First we replace the #% with the actual percentage
const stringWithPercentage = data.key.replace('#%', `(${data.value[0][0]}-${data.value[0][1]})%`)

// Then we can use that value and replace the last # with the seconds
const stringWithSeconds = stringWithPercentage.replace('#', data.value[1][0])

console.log(stringWithSeconds)
```

There are several ways of achieving this depending on your needs and your willingness to change the data structure.